# Assigning an IP to a wired IP Camera over WiFi

Tags: networking, router, camera

My PC is connected to my network via Wifi (Wired is currently not an option). I want to test an IP camera at my desk. It's a POE camera so I want to plug the POE (unmanaged) switch into my ethernet port on the PC and the camera into the switch. How can I get the router to assign the camera an IP address or some how set up Windows to act as a router? Temporarily disabling WiFi is ok.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bridge from Wifi to Ethernet not working (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1386649/bridge-from-wifi-to-ethernet-not-working-windows-10)

Comment: The Internet Connection Sharing feature in Windows may help (assuming you're using windows, if not, please specify your PC OS). Your other option may be to set up a wireless bridge: https://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/howto-connect-two-wireless-router-wirelessly-bridge-with-open-source-software/

Comment: Wouldn't i need 2 routers for a bridge to work?

Comment: You don't want a bridge.  You want to share the Wifi connection (in order to get a DHCP request satisfied).  Did you even read the suggested answer?