# Internet access via shared connection (Windows)

Tags: windows, networking, connection-sharing

I have a Windows 11 PC sharing its (wireless LAN) Internet connection via an Ethernet adapter (`192.168.137.1/24`):

```
Wireless LAN adapter WLAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : router.local
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.62
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 6:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c473:b359:2bd3:fb0%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

[image]

A second PC (connected via Ethernet) has the following setup for its Ethernet adapter:

```
Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::51e6:fd36:9678:15fb%12
   IPv4-Adress . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.2
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
```

the routing table has the correct entry:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.137.1    192.168.137.2    281
(...)

===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Netzworkaddress          Netmask    Gatewayaddress  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.137.1  Standard
===========================================================================
```

the PC's can ping each other (on `192.168.137.1` and `192.168.137.2`) but pinging `8.8.8.8` from PC2 does not work anymore (as far as I remember it used to work after I first tried the setup). Any idea what the problem might be?

**I tried:**

- the Internet connection is working for PC1
- deactivating the firewall on PC1 didn't improve anything
- deactivating IP6 (both adapters) didn't improve anything
- tracert just shows timeouts

Comment: Consider packet capture on PC1?

Comment: @TomYan not yet, I didn't set up Wireshark yet (I hope there is a simpler solution)

Comment: Try disable and re-enable the ICS, heh (smells like something wrong with the NAT, so if possible, perhaps it's even better to packet capture on PC1's default gateway).

Comment: reinitializing the ICS did the trick... should have tried that in the first place, thanks!

Comment: @TomYan Restarting the laptop would have probably done the trick as well, feel free to write an answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was your approach to troubleshot via packet capture?

Comment: To be frank, I don't have a better solution attempt than resetting / toggling ICS anyway. (Isn't resetting / toggling the way to fix things in Windows for most of the time though?) I was just kinda curious whether it was due the IP forwarding is down, or whether the NAT'ing is down / has gone haywire somehow.

Comment: @TomYan Seems to be a common issue, it happened a few times now, and reinitializing always helped. If you want to add an answer, feel free, otherwise, I can do it as well in order to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the internet sharing worked fine. Although I ended up [creating a WLAN to Ethernet bridge](https://superuser.com/a/1580432/201818) which ended up being much more stable.