# Kali Linux bridged adapter won't work with Media Tek MT7921 Wi-Fi 802llax PCle Adapter

Tags: kali-linux

I have the VM Box 7.0.10 and the Kali Linux 2032.2 version. It's all current but when I try to run it with a bridged adapter it won't work. Any help would be appreciated. I am new here and to cybersecurity and want to figure this out. If you need more information just let me know what you need to help me. The driver version is 3.0.1.1303.

Comment: [Wi-Fi client interfaces generally cannot be bridged.](https://superuser.com/a/1386651/219095)

Answer (score 0):

Media Tek MT7921 Wi-Fi 802llax PCle Adapter is a Wireless Adapter.

If you have this adapter on the Host machine and the Host machine is connected to your router, then Bridged mode should work.

I am in Kali 2023.3 and my Host Machine is Wireless and it connects in Bridged mode just fine.

Just make sure you have only the one network device for Host and Guest.

You can try substituting a different Host network device (Ethernet for example) to see if that works.

**Added Information:**

If you wish to use a Wireless card for Kali for Monitor Mode and forensic / penetration studies, what you are doing will not work.

You need a proper USB Wireless Adapter that supports Monitor Mode and use USB Pass Through to install and use it. I use a Panda USB wireless card for this and it does work (Monitor Mode and all).

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I appreciate it!

Comment: I think I have answered your question here.